# Align- and border issues of a table

Tags: html, css, drupal

For some reason, the table-styles on this advertisement page (the image of the laptop and the specifications).
Normally, it should have a border and vertical-align in the middle.

I found there was a `reset.css`-stylesheet which is responsible for the bad-alignment. But I have no idea how to overwrite this setting in my normal `styles.css` file. Not using the `reset.css` file isn't an option.

Concerning the border-issue: I don't find where the border visibility (or size) is set to non... So if anyone could see this and tell me how to get the border visible again, that would be more then great!

The content managers use CKEditor to create this kind of content:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The border is not set to none..

There is a `style` attribute (*hardcoded*) on the 2 `td` elements that manually set the border color to white

```
<td style="border-bottom-color: #ffffff; border-top-color: #ffffff; width: 252px; border-right-color: #ffffff; border-left-color: #ffffff">...</td>
```

You need to remove that.

---

For the `vertical-align` issue just write a rule with

```
td{vertical-align:middle;}
```

and make sure your own style sheet comes ***after*** the `reset.css` file..

(*keep in mind that it will apply to all `td` elements*)

Comment: @Michiel just added that as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it's a Drupal website and the content managers are using CKEditor (see new screenshot in my question), so I find it hard to believe it converts the borders to #ffffff...

Comment: doesn't matter if you find it hard.. look at the source code, the inline style is there.. (*perhaps the managers have made the border white for some reason and forgot to remove it afterwords..*)

Comment: Yes, I see it's hard coded. But I'm just wondering why. Thanks for you input though!

Comment: @Michiel, maybe there is a default style/setting that the CK editor applies to tables..

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
Border color you have set to white ? how you can see in white background ?

```
<td style="border:1px solid #000000;vertical-align:middle" valign="middle">
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the table. Go to the row or tr

use:

```
<tr valign="top|middle|bottom">
```

And inside that row the v align of text/imgs will depende on the value of valign.

For table borders for each rows/column:

```
table td {
    border:1px solid red;
}
```